# How to retrieve a value of a "belongs to" element attribute on an index page in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I try to make a web application where I have 4 models :
User, Recipe, Step, Steps_advancement.

Globally, a user can like a recipe composed by steps. When the user opens and reads a step of the recipe, it puts a "is_read=true" on the table steps_advancement which belongs to user and step.

For the moment I have this code :

Models :

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user
has_many :steps
has_many :favorites
has_many :favorited_by_users, :through => :favorites, :source => 'user'

class Step < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :recipe
has_one :steps_advancement
end

class StepsAdvancement < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :step 
belongs_to :user
end

class Favorite < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :recipe
belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
has_many :recipes
has_many :favorites
has_many :favorite_recipes, :through => :favorites, :source => 'recipe’
has_many :steps_advancements

devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
 :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
end
```

In the database, i have a table Steps_advancement with a boolean "is_read", default: false, null: false (and recipe_id and step_id on index)

In the views, the steps index page lists all the steps of the recipe.
I want to be able to retrieve, in the steps index view, the value of the steps_advancement ‘is_read’. In order to display it if the previous is read, or hide it, else. 
But I can't, I have an error message.

StepsController

```
def index
@recipe = Recipe.find(params[:recipe_id])
@steps = @recipe.steps
```

in the steps index view (index.html.erb)

```
<% if current_user %>        
<% @steps.each do |st|%>                    
<% if st.steps_advancement.is_read?%>   # <<< error here        
<%= link_to([@recipe, steps]) do %>

<strong><%=st.name %></strong> --             
<%else%>

<%="not avalaible for the moment!"%>

<% end %>       
<% end %>
```

In the third line I have a problem. I cannot access the steps_advancement. I guess rails does not recognize the step but how can i resolve it ? :)

In advance thanks!

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Hi! it is said :  "undefined method `is_read?' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: seems you dn't have any data in `StepsAdvancement` for your `step` your code is fine but you dnt have any `StepsAdvancement` regarding step use pry and check or at rails console check if it has any data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `step_advancement` is not created on `step` until it is read, correct?

Add a `try` before `is_read?` like such:

#### steps/index.html.erb

```
<% if current_user %>        
<% @steps.each do |st|%>                    
<% if st.steps_advancement.try(:is_read?)%>   # <<< error here        
<%= link_to([@recipe, steps]) do %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will work, but you can try to add nested attributes for

```
class Step < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :recipe
  has_one :steps_advancement
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :steps_advancement

 def steps_advancement
    self.steps_advancement
 end
end
```

**EDIT**
I don't know if could work but maybe that could be a workaround solution

Comment: Hi! thanks for your answer, yes i already try this but it did not work more ;) but thanks!

Comment: I edit my answer adding a method to retrieve your steps_advancement, maybe it could work :)

Answer (score 0):

use this:

seems your code is fine here i'm skipping `<% if st.steps_advancement.is_read?%>` block if `st.steps_advancement` is blank.

```
   <% if current_user %>        
      <% @steps.each do |st|%> 
        <%next if st.steps_advancement.blank?%>                   
        <% if st.steps_advancement.is_read?%>   # <<< error here        
          <%= link_to([@recipe, steps]) do %>
          <strong><%=st.name %></strong> --             
        <%else%>
          <%="not avalaible for the moment!"%>
        <% end %> 
      <%end%>      
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this! It works with the "try" too (from the message below). Thank you very much for your help